# Find the inverse function for $y=12.263\ln(x)-45.381$

Tags: logarithms, inverse

Find the inverse function for $y=12.263\ln(x)-45.381$

So I did $x=12.263\ln(y)-45.381$ and solved for $y$ to get:

$e^{\frac{x+45.381}{12.263}}$ But it says this answer is incorrect. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

The correct answer is:

[image]

I suspect a change of basis formula is at work here and that my answer is actually equal to the "correct" answer. Can anyone clarify what's going on for me here?

Comment: Who/what told you it is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry! I updated the question with precise values. My teacher said this was incorrect on my homework.

Comment: The transformation is correct. Usually a function has a domain. Maybe this is what your teacher want.

Comment: There are many different ways to write the answer. Did anyone tell you what **is** the correct answer?

Comment: I updated my question with the correct answer... I'm hoping someone here will expand on how to go from my answer to the given answer!

Comment: $$
e^{\frac{{x + 45.381}}{{12.263}}}  = e^{\frac{{45.381}}{{12.263}}}  \cdot e^{\frac{x}{{12.263}}}  = e^{\frac{{45.381}}{{12.263}}}  \cdot (e^{\frac{1}{{12.263}}} )^x  \approx 40.473(1.085)^x .
$$ Your answer is the correct one. The "correct answer" is just an approximation, which in fact, becomes worse and worse as $x$ becomes larger and larger.

Comment: @Gary: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
e^{\frac{{x + 45.381}}{{12.263}}}  = e^{\frac{{45.381}}{{12.263}}}  \cdot e^{\frac{x}{{12.263}}}  = e^{\frac{{45.381}}{{12.263}}}  \cdot (e^{\frac{1}{{12.263}}} )^x  \approx 40.473(1.085)^x .
$$
Your answer is the correct one. The "correct answer" is just an approximation which, in fact, becomes worse and worse as $x$ becomes larger and larger. For $x=10000$, the relative error will already be about $40\%$.